# Azure Search - restrict users from seeing some results

Tags: azure, search

We would like Azure Search to be able to restrict search results for certain users by some means – we are considering using the filter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters) option for this.
So far, we understand that the search query and the search results from Azure Search would be public and unencrypted.
Is there a way that the search query can be encrypted so that a user cannot meddle with the filter values and see data he is not authorized to see?
Similarly, for the results, in there a way to prevent an unauthorized person from seeing the results returned from Azure Search?

Answer (score 0):

There's encryption at rest an in transit, but ideally you should implement your own authorization mechanism to handle what users can see. There's no ready to use feature for it.